# Using an if statement to decided whether or not to show a table on a jsp page

Tags: java, jsp

I have a parameter of user that I am setting equal to -1 if this param is not given.  I only want to show the table if the parameter is fulfilled ( for instance if user = 1 ).

- so using an "if" statement.....can I just do something like this:

ex:

```
if(user >= 1){
<table>
<tr>
.....
</tr>
</table>
}
```

Is this possible, or how would you recommend doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Request parameters are as a `Map<String, String>` available by `${param}` in EL. So a request parameter with the name `user` is available by `${param.user}`.

[JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) provides the core tags like `<c:if>` to control the flow in the page.

So, 1 + 1 = ...

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
...
<c:if test="${param.user > 0}">
    <table>
        ...
    </table>
</c:if>
```

Comment: This works great, I was not at all familiar with this solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to use JSTL.   [`<c:if>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) tag, also to set the parameter as attribute in `request` to use it on jsp

Comment: I am not familiar with this, is this the only thing that is needed?

Comment: This is the standard thing. *choice is yours*

Answer (score 0):

```
<% if(user >= 1){ %>

some html

<% } %>
```

Comment: the use of scriptlets its not so good but you can get the same efect with jstl (http://jstl.java.net/)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try to intermix Java scriptlets inside JSP. Use [JSTL](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core/if.html) instead. You would have to import the core library `<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tld/c.tld" prefix="c" %>` and include jstl.jar standard.jar in your classpath which can be found on the [Apache Site](http://jakarta.apache.org/site/downloads/downloads_taglibs-standard.cgi)